# Why does the Nova Corps list Gamora as the last of her species?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In *Guardians of the Galaxy* we see Gamora's rap sheet say

> Origin: Last survivor of the Zehoberei people

[image: Gamora's Rap Sheet]

[image: Gamora's Rap Sheet zoomed to relevant quote]

However, in *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos says to Gamora

> **Gamora:** I was a child when you took me.
>   **Thanos:** I saved you.
>   **Gamora:** No. No. We were happy on my home planet.
>   **Thanos:** Going to bed hungry, scrounging for scraps. Your planet was on the brink of collapse. I'm the one who stopped that. **Do you know what's happened since then? The children born have known nothing but full bellies and clear skies. It's a paradise.**
>
> <sub><sup>Sources: [Transcripts Wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsZ65.jpg), [Springfield Springfield](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War)</sup></sub>

Since Gamora's people are still alive, why does Nova Corps have on record that she's the last?

Comment: Same question on Movies & TV Stack Exchange: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88700/11182

Comment: "Zehoberei" is a religion on her planet.. There's no inconsistency..

Comment: @user931 Would you consider turning your comment into an answer, citing a source that describes "Zehoberei" as a religion?

Comment: Rule Number One: Thanos does not actually keep detailed progress reports on every planet he’s Demi-genocided.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### In-universe

No explanation is given for this discrepancy. Given that Thanos is in possession of the Space and Mind stones (granting him what essentially amounts to near-omniscience) and given that he's a pretty honourable guy (in his own twisted way) it seems unlikely that he's lying to Gamora.

That being said, it seems more likely that the Nova Corp's records about Gamora's home planet are simply incorrect. If they're not in regular contact with her planet then they may be relying on secondary sources of information that she hasn't bothered to put right.

### Out-of-universe

We may now know what director James Gunn was referring to in an interview he gave prior to the film's release. He and the VFX team apparently used information from the *comics* (in which Gamora's planet was [destroyed by Adam Warlock](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Zen-Whoberis)) when they wrote the text for the mugshots, not realising that this would conflict with a later plot-point that he wanted to make.

> *“I’m writing Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 and I finished the first draft of the treatment yesterday. I’m excited about it. I feel really great about it. But there’s one little thing that I had in the first movie. Now, Marvel Canon – MCU – is crazy. There’s the 616 universe which is the Marvel Comics Universe, which people get hung up on that canon, and then there’s the MCU, The Marvel Cinematic Universe, which has a separate canon (inspired by but not exactly the same as the 616.) I did something in the first movie of Guardians where it was in the background but it was distinctly there, and people know that it’s there. And I’m like goddammit. Because I have a really good storytelling reason for breaking the canon, and I stayed up last night figuring out if I’m gonna do it or not. I still don’t know.”*
>
> *“I’ll actually tell ya. In the first movie there is the mugshot sequence where the characters go through and they’re going through the mugshots and having their picture taken. And the Nova Corps has information about each of the characters coming up on their machinery. Those things are something that your average viewer doesn’t see at all. But there’s a lot of background I put into those things about who they’ve worked with, where they are from, what’s going on. And it’s one of those things that I’m thinking about changing.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[James Gunn May Break His Own MCU Canon in ‘Guardians of the Galaxy 3’](https://www.slashfilm.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-3-story/)</sup></sub>

Comment: A simple solution could also be that the children who are now born on Gamora's planet are not of her species.

Comment: @Erik - In what way would that be a simple solution?

Comment: It makes her "the last of her species" despite there being "children born on her world".

Comment: Or an explanation for why the records are wrong. It would be simple enough to have a throw-away line about Nova Corps needing to update their records or similar.

Comment: It's also possible that the "Zehoberei" people (at least in the MCU) are an *ethnicity* rather than a *species* per se. The mug shot does say "people" and not "species". This could be like how it could, in theory, be possible for a catastrophe to befall humanity such that there are still thousands of Han Chinese, Jews, Irish, and Navajo around but only one "last" Basque person, the "last survivor of the Basque people".

Comment: @Erik - Maybe I'm being thick, but what would cause them to be a different species in less than 20 years? Or have you invented an apocalypse of some description?

Comment: Erik appears to be saying that Thanos is not referring to Gamora's species in this quote: "The children born have known nothing but full bellies and clear skies." It doesn't make much sense in context to the quote but it is an interpretation of it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Just to be clear, the assertion would then be that the planet housed multiple species, and the Zehoberei (except Gamora) simply all lost the coin flip? (or the few that maybe survived the coin flip are dead by now for unrelated reasons?)

Comment: @Flater I don't know you'd have to ask Erik. I was just trying to explain what I thought they meant.

Comment: If it's an ethnicity, she can just be the last pure blood. With half population, they would have mix to assure enought gen pool..

Comment: Nitpick time: Strictly speaking, Adam Warlock did not kill everyone on Gamora's planet. It was the Universal Church of Truth that did, under the leadership of Adam's future self, The Magus.

Comment: I agree with what @Erik said (and I believe it is clarified correctly), and would invite them to make that a proper answer so I can upvote it. Simply reply to me so I remember to come back

Comment: @Trikly - The problem is that we want evidence here, not fan-fiction

Comment: Of course, since GotG1 came out, the comics revealed some other survivors of her homeworld, stuck in/near the event horizon of a black hole (which is why no one knew they were there). If I'm remembering the *Gamora* mini-series correctly, that is.